# Is visting websites like wiki-islam/Quora/reddit ex-muslim prohibited?

Tags: halal-haram, quran, internet

There are two verses in the Quran that address this question, [Surah An-Nisa - 4:140 | Quran.com](https://quran.com/4/140):

> He has already revealed to you in the Book that when you hear Allah’s revelations being denied or ridiculed, then do not sit in that company unless they engage in a different topic, or else you will be like them.1 Surely Allah will gather the hypocrites and disbelievers all together in Hell.

and [Surah Al-An'am - 6:68 | Quran.com](https://quran.com/6/68),

> And when you come across those who ridicule Our revelations, do not sit with them unless they engage in a different topic. Should Satan make you forget, then once you remember, do not ˹continue to˺ sit with the wrongdoing people.

listed in order.

The above verses are clear that a muslim shouldn't sit with people who mock Islam.
Does visiting sites like reddit/ex-Muslim, wikiislam and quora where Islam is mocked and ridiculed prohibited as per above verse? Does watching videos(non debates) of david wood also fall in the above category?

Comment: You should not give free publicity to such people/websites by mentioning them to public.

Comment: Warning against evil?

Comment: Warning against evil is to people who already aware of it or might be falling victim to it.
So if you specifically know such a person, sure go ahead and warn. But most of the general public is not even aware of it. So if someone comes to know about such sites, and then just of or curiosity, visits them, you know what kind of effect it may have. And you don't want to be the reason for someone to doubt or may Allaah forbid, leave Islam.

Also there is a saying "any publicity is good publicity". We need to keep that in consideration.

Answer (score 2):

> ...then do not sit in that company unless they engage in a different topic, or else you will be like them...

I think you misunderstood the verse. This verse talks about you being **silent** when others ridicule Quran or Islam. Then what about preaching to other religious people? Of course they will ask and ridicule Islam, and it is your duty to clarify their accusation and doubts.

If you cannot be with people who ridicule Islam, you cannot debate with them about what is the truth.

So I'd say the verse talks about you being silent to talk back, just go away. Otherwise you are considered one of them too.

So it is okay if you are there to debate, to clear their accusation and ridicules, it is okay to see what others think about Islam and help them to the right way to view Islam. But if they are ridiculing Islam without a proper reason like debating and just ridicule for the sake of ridiculing, just get out of there. Idiots will not debate for what is right.

Comment: it is not for everyone to debate, or clarify or defend against the accusations made by people about Islam. It takes a person of very strong eeman and knowledge to do so. Lest the person himself might fall into doubt about his own eeman. For a lay-person, it is always better to avoid this.

Comment: Of course it is not for everyone to debate and answer the questions, but I'm only answering what the verse says and nothing else. If you can't debate just don't sit with them, thats what the verse also says.

Comment: It is in general a waist of time to debate with people who know Islam and refuse. That's why it is discouraged, see above. To my experience it does make sense to debate with people who reject Islam because of lack of knowledge; e.g. rejecting Islam because of ISIS or other terrorists.

Answer (score -1):

I'd say you should stay away from them as they make your mind doubt Allah, as it happened with me from David Wood but I recited the Shahadah and I no longer watch his mokery. As for being haraam? I don't think it is.

Comment: “I don’t think its haraam” But you did not use any reasoning to come to this conclusion